# How do I neatly remove pma tables from mysql without affecting phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, uninstallation

I have a problem with my phpMyAdmin installation. I accidentally clicked something that creates the pma tables used by phpMyAdmin. And rather stupidly, I created them in a client's database. Although I haven't activated advanced features in my config.inc.php file (all the pma stuff is commented out), phpMyAdmin still needs them for some reason, because it stops working whenever I delete the pma tables (giving errors about not finding table pma__...).

Could someone please tell me how I can completely disable "advanced features" in phpMyAdmin and so remove these pma tables?

Answer (score 0):

This result was highly rated in google, and even though its a bit old, I just thought I'd put up how I fixed this.

I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to databases, but I recently had this problem on a test machine, and my solution was as follows (This may be dangerous, so backup and have a plan to recover in case of issues).
**This deletes the phpmyadmin database** (Which I think is safe to do, but someone else would be better qualified to answer this)

Log into your mysql database via command line (eg :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your password, then drop the phpmyadmin database

```
drop database phpmyadmin
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I logged out of phpmyadmin and back in, and it worked.